# Adding a count field not in models to GET request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model of Gun, and each gun has multiple Loads

What I want to do is add a Load count to the gun GET request object, but not in the model it self. So the count is done when I do the GET request, and only for the GET request if possible. Otherwise I can just make the POST load_count = 0, because there is no such field and It should not be saved.

```
class Gun(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Load(models.Model):
    gun = models.ForeignKey(Gun, related_name='gun')
    foo = ...
```

Serializers:

```
class GunSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ??? load_count = Field() -- reverse lookup and count loads
    id = serializers.Field()
    class Meta:
        model = Gun
        fields = ('id',"name", ???? "load_count")


class LoadSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.Field()
    class Meta:
        model = Load
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using an IntegerField for the set count:

```
class GunSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    load_count = serializers.IntegerField(source='load_set.count')

    class Meta:
        model = Gun
        fields = ('id', "name", "load_count")
```

However, you are using the `related_name` of `gun` in your Load model which I would recommend changing to `loads` (or just omitting and then use the default `load_set` and the example above will work). If you want to keep the related name of `gun` then define the load_count serializer field as:

```
load_count = serializers.IntegerField(source='gun.count')
```

Comment: That raises the excpetion 'Gun' object has no attribute 'load_set'

Comment: Ahh, I think it is because of your `related_name` in your models, which is a bit backwards, it should be something like `related_name='loads'` and then you would use `source='loads.count'`

Comment: According to his model the `related_name` is `gun` so it would have to be `source='gun.count'`. But it's probably better readable if he were to simply change that to `loads`

Comment: @EWit yeah, I kinda implied that with my comment, which perhaps wasn't the clearest way.  I've updated the answer to make this more explicit. Thanks!